# python pandas groupby sort rank/top n

Tags: python, pandas, rank

I have a dataframe that is grouped by state and aggregated to total revenue where sector and name are ignored.  I would now like to break the underlying dataset out to show state, sector, name and the top 2 by revenue in a certain order(i have a created an index from a previous dataframe that lists states in a certain order).  Using the below example, I would like to use my sorted index (Kentucky, California, New York) that lists only the top two results per state (in previously stated order by Revenue):
Dataset:

```
State       Sector   Name   Revenue
California  1        Tom    10
California  2        Harry  20
California  3        Roger  30
California  2        Jim    40
Kentucky    2        Bob    15
Kentucky    1        Roger  25
Kentucky    3        Jill   45
New York    1        Sally  50
New York    3        Harry  15
```

End Goal Dataframe:

```
State       Sector   Name   Revenue
Kentucky    3        Jill   45
Kentucky    1        Roger  25
California  2        Jim    40
California  3        Roger  30
New York    1        Sally  50
New York    3        Harry  15
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a `groupby` in conjunction with `apply`:

```
df.groupby('State').apply(lambda grp: grp.nlargest(2, 'Revenue'))
```

Output:

```
                     Sector Name    Revenue
State       State           
California  California  2   Jim     40
            California  3   Roger   30
Kentucky    Kentucky    3   Jill    45
            Kentucky    1   Roger   25
New York    New York    1   Sally   50
            New York    3   Harry   15
```

Then you can drop the first level of the `MultiIndex` to get the result you're after:

```
df.index = df.index.droplevel()
```

Output:

```
         Sector Name    Revenue
State           
California  2   Jim     40
California  3   Roger   30
Kentucky    3   Jill    45
Kentucky    1   Roger   25
New York    1   Sally   50
New York    3   Harry   15
```

Comment: thank you!  This is great, the nlargest is important as i will be exporting the outcome to xcel, vs head().  Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 6):

You can `sort_values` then using `groupby` + `head`

```
df.sort_values('Revenue',ascending=False).groupby('State').head(2)
Out[208]: 
        State  Sector   Name  Revenue
7     NewYork       1  Sally       50
6    Kentucky       3   Jill       45
3  California       2    Jim       40
2  California       3  Roger       30
5    Kentucky       1  Roger       25
8     NewYork       3  Harry       15
```